# Hypersurface containing nondegenerate subvariety of same degree and large dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Can a smooth hypersurface $X\subset \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{n+1}$ of degree $d$ contain a nondegenerate variety $Z$ with $\dim(Z)>\frac{n}{2}$ of degree $d$?

(If $r$ is the codimension of $Z$ in $X$, an application of Lefschetz hyperplane theorem will show that the Poincare dual of $Z$ in $H^{2r}(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is homologous to the dual of the intersection of a general $n+1-r$-plane with $X$, but does that show $Z$ is degenerate?)

Cross posted on mathstackexchange in a slightly different form: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945786/nondegenerate-subvariety-of-prime-degree-not-contained-in-smooth-hypersurface)

Comment: There are nontrivial constraints on $Z$ beyond the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem imposed by the fact that various intersection products $([Z]\cdot [W])_X$ can be computed via excess intersection from $Z\cap W$, cf. "A Fact about Linear Spaces on Hypersurfaces".  I do not know if those constraints are enough to prove that $Z$ is a linear section of $X$.

Comment: Missing the hypothesis that $d$ is prime?  This hypothesis is made in the mathstackexchange question.  Without it one can surely concoct examples such as: $Z$ is a smooth intersection $Q_1 = Q_2 = 0$ of quadrics contained in any hypersurface $X$ of the form $q_1 Q_1 + q_2 Q_2 = 0$ (with $q_i$ also of degree $2$).

Comment: Is that hypersurface smooth though?

Comment: I don't know; is there some problem like the common zero-locus of the $q_i$ and $Q_i$ that one wouldn't see in low dimensions?

Comment: I would guess so - that hypersurface contains $D=\{q_1=Q_2=0\}$ as a Weil divisor which doesn't appear to be Cartier.

Comment: In fact, that hypersurface is singular along the locus $q_1=q_2=Q_1=Q_2=0$.